# Algorithm for procedural city generation?

Tags: java, procedural

I am planning on making a (simple) procedural city generator using Java. I need ideas on whan algorithm to use for the layout, and the actual buildings. The city will mostly have skyscrapers, not really much complex stuff.

For the layout I already have a simple algorithm implemented:

1. Create a Map with java.awt.Point keys and Integer values. Fill it with all the points in the city's bounds with the value as -1 (unnassigned)
2. Shuffle the map, and assign the 1st 10 of the keys IDs (from 1-10)
3. Loop until all points have IDs:
4. Loop though all points:
5. Assign points next to an assigned point IDs of the point next to them, if 2 or more points border the point, then randomly choose which ID the point will get.
6. Stop looping #3-5 when all points have ids
7. You will end up with 10 random regions. Make roads bordering these regions.
8. Fill the inside of each region with a randomly spaced and randomly rotated grid

**PROBLEM:** This is not the *fastest* way to do it.

What algorithm should I use for the layout. And what should I use to make each building's design? I don't even know how I'm going to do that yet (fractals maybe). I just need some ideas, not actual code.

Comment: I'm not sure the algorithm will work as you list it out.  In step 3, you assign all points IDs.  In step 5, you assign points next to an assigned point (which is all of the points) the ID of the point next to them.  So you're going through and changing all of the IDs points you have assigned.  Because of this, you'll have a jumble of tiny little islands of each ID, not 10 individual regions.

Comment: relevant:  Pixel City.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-d2-PtK4F6Y

Comment: it doesn't explain you how it is done, but might give you some ideas : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FR9xI0GgrBY (city) and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUwHRc2zpbo (office generation)

Comment: Saskia Groenewegen's thesis might give you some ideas: http://graphics.tudelft.nl/Game_Technology/Groenewegen

Comment: @Trevor - Shamus has had a blog about this for a while. A very good read in my opinion. http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=2940

Comment: wow. I like the pixel city. I am trying something like that, except in Java...

Comment: @fnord no step 3 means "do the below steps until this objective is achieved" step 3 does not actually assign points IDs. Step 5 is similar

Comment: @Zove Games Ahhh... so steps 4 and 5 are inside the loops of the step above them.  That makes more sense, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The procedure you've described seems to be about generating a number of regions on your map.  For this problem, I'd suggest using a [voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) instead.  A nice tutorial for generating one can be found [here.](http://donhavey.com/blog/tutorials/tutorial-7-voronoi-diagrams/)  I think this would be faster than your algorithm.

Looking further ahead to road and building generation, there are a lot of different algorithms because of the different requirements.  Is this a modern American city with sky-scrapers and suburbs or a historic Roman city with temples and 1-story buildings?  This type of difference will affect what you want from your city generator.

If you're interested in reading some academic stuff, I'd recommend a [couple](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~pascmu/documents/procedural_modeling_of_cities__siggraph2001.pdf) of [papers](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~pascmu/documents/mueller.procedural_modeling_of_buildings.SG2006.web-version.pdf) on Pascal Müller's site.

Comment: it's a modern american city. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thanks for the answer though. I'll look into the voronoi diagrams.